# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'default') in my next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, typeerror

```
"use client"
import { useKindeBrowserClient } from '@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs'
import Image from 'next/image';
import React from 'react'

function DashboardHeader() {

  const {user} = useKindeBrowserClient();
  return (
   <div>
    <Image src={user?.picture} alt='logo'
    width={40}
    height={40}
    /> 
   </div>
  )
}

export default DashboardHeader
```

I am getting this error in my webapp, I m getting this error because of image tag in the provided code.

I have noticed once I remove this image tag code, everything works fine. But the moment I write this image tag code, this issue pop up.

I tried everything but can't solve this.

Comment: Try to add this line  **before** return and share the console output with us: `console.log(JSON.stringify(user, null, 2));`

Comment: I got null in console and same errors

Comment: app-index.js:33 
 Image is missing required "src" property: 
DashboardHeader.jsx:9 {
  "family_name": "Goyal",
  "given_name": "Rashap",
  "picture": null,
  "email": "rashapofficial11@gmail.com",
  "id": "kp_a8e870b112554c21b7f3d0c7b78e117e"
}

Comment: I m unable to upload the screenshot here, otherwise I would have share the exact console red errors

Comment: I suspected this - the `user.picture` object is empty - but @grekier already answered it for me. I want to add that **the second of the two versions** given by him **is more user-friendly**. In the case of the first, if `user.picture` is null, the `img` tag will not be created, thus the website layout may fall apart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that `Image` doesn't like null `src`. You should change your code to something like:

```
"use client"
import { useKindeBrowserClient } from '@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs'
import Image from 'next/image';
import React from 'react'

function DashboardHeader() {

  const {user} = useKindeBrowserClient();
  return (
   <div>
    {user?.picture && <Image src={user?.picture} alt='logo'
    width={40}
    height={40}
    />}
   </div>
  )
}

export default DashboardHeader
```

To drop the `Image` if you don't have the data or:

```
"use client"
import { useKindeBrowserClient } from '@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs'
import Image from 'next/image';
import React from 'react'

function DashboardHeader() {

  const {user} = useKindeBrowserClient();
  return (
   <div>
    <Image src={user?.picture ? user.picture : '/some/fallback.png'} alt='logo'
    width={40}
    height={40}
    /> 
   </div>
  )
}

export default DashboardHeader
```

to get a fallback image.

Comment: Thanku so much. The issue resolved with ur provided code

Comment: Yes I accepted the answer, Thanks:)  Hope to get more help in future in my projects as I m a beginner developer :)